# Which of the followings is correct?

Tags: group-theory

**Which of the followings is correct?**

[image]

I'm absolutely clueless! I can't get how such a non-zero homomorphism is possible!

Comment: You are right - this makes no sense! $f$ is necessarily the zero homomorphism. So $A$ should be correct. But it cannot be, as $f$ is stipulated as being non-zero.

Comment: @user1729 Ex falso quodlibet, ergo: all of the above.

Comment: More down to earth, I suspect it's a simple typo and $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ was intended.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Let us consider the question should as you pointed out i.e. $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_6.$ Then I think only (D) is correct. For $f:1\mapsto (2)$ is a non-zero homomorphism which is neither onto nor 1-1. **Am I right?**

Comment: @SritiMallick Correct. Obviously not zero, obviously not injective, and projecting onto $\mathbb{Z}_3$ contradcits surjectivity.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Thanks so much.

Comment: @SritiMallick I have a few reservations about the assertiveness of "none of the above holds", since $f$ can be surjective, but yes, that would be the correct answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - this makes no sense! Any homomorphism from a finite cyclic group to the infinite cyclic group $F: C\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is necessarily the zero homomorphism, collapsing the whole of $C$ to the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$. So $A$ should be correct. But it cannot be, as $f$ is stipulated as being non-zero. Therefore, the question is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What's $6f(x)$ for any $x$?

Comment: Exactly! If $f(1)\neq 0$ then $f(0)=f(6)$ is necessarily non-zero.

Comment: @SritiMallick It's a typo.